# Android TV 11 change mouse cursor size

Tags: settings, android-tv, mouse

Hi am using Android TV for TCL brand. The Android TV OS version is 11.
TV+ OS version: v5.2.0
The mouse cursor size is too large.
Can anyone tell me how to reduce its size.
I dont see the option in Accessibility menu or in Developer Options menu as found on web search.
Is there any other way the cursor size can be modified?